# Slow tomcat startup

Tags: tomcat, startup

I have very slow Tomcat start with app deployment.

Environment:

OS: Scientific Linux 6.3 x86_64

Java: 1.7.0_9 64bit

Tomcat: 7.0.32

startup tooks 150s and java process is at 100% CPU

I tried same webapp on another server (with same HW parameters) but on OS 32bit with java6 32bit and tomcat 7.0.19 and on this server tomcat starts in 30s.

I tried same java and same tomcat on new server without much success.

here is parts of tomcat logs when it waits for something...

```
FINE: Setting state for [WebappLoader[]] to [STARTING]
Nov 19, 2012 1:23:13 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase setStateInternal
FINE: Setting state for [WebappLoader[]] to [STARTED]
Nov 19, 2012 1:24:06 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase setStateInternal
FINE: Setting state for StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[].StandardWrapper[starthead]] to [INITIALIZING]
```

...

```
Nov 19, 2012 1:24:06 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase setStateInternal
FINE: Setting state for [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[].StandardWrapper[default]] to [STARTED]
Nov 19, 2012 1:24:26 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase setStateInternal
FINE: Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources@2acd47cb] to [INITIALIZING]
Nov 19, 2012 1:24:26 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase setStateInternal
FINE: Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources@2acd47cb] to [INITIALIZED]
```

...

```
Nov 19, 2012 1:24:26 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase setStateInternal
FINE: Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]] to [STARTED]
Nov 19, 2012 1:25:23 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase setStateInternal
FINE: Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager[]] to [INITIALIZING]
Nov 19, 2012 1:25:23 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase setStateInternal
```

...

```
FINE: Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager[]] to [STARTING]
Nov 19, 2012 1:25:23 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase setStateInternal
FINE: Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager[]] to [STARTED]
Nov 19, 2012 1:25:43 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase setStateInternal
FINE: Setting state for [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]] to [STARTING]
Nov 19, 2012 1:25:43 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase setStateInternal
```

So where is problem?

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade to Tomcat 7.0.33?

Answer (score 3):

Set `tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip` property in conf/catalina.properties file and configure jars not to be scanned for TLD files.

See http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo/FasterStartUp